# Flowplayer getTime as a float

Tags: flowplayer

So, the flowplayer documentation says that there are two ways to get the current play time of a Player object. `getTime()` and `getStatus().time`. Unfortunately, both of those return int's (in seconds), and I am creating a screen-shot and need to get the current timestamp in 1/10th's of a second (and 1/100 is even better). Is it possible to get a more accurate value (ideally in JS, I can manage AS if necessary but that is annoying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apparently there is no way to retrieve that information.